# How I can copy Data recursive from position A to position B with Powershell?

Tags: windows, file, powershell, transfer, unc

i want to create a powershell script that can copy data from position a to position b recursive.

this must do it with UNC-Paths.

On position b must all empty Orders delete.

I don't know how I can start :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both position A and position B need to be local paths or shares on the given server in this example.

```
$a = '\\serverA\folderA'
$b = '\\serverB\folderB'

#This copies the files
Get-ChildItem $a -Recurse -File | Foreach_Object {Copy-Item $_ -Destination $b}

#Removes empty files
Get-ChildItem $b -File | Foreach-Object {IF($_.Length -eq 0) {Remove-Item $_}}
```

Comment: Yes this is in a network with diffrent computers. i want to copy all files from a folder and subfolders to a other position. ^^

Comment: Edited my post, that should be all you need.